# Swift if statement - multiple conditions separated by commas?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, option-type

Looking at a Swift [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1):

```
if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? MealViewController, meal = sourceViewController.meal {
    ...
}
```

The doc states:

> ... the code assigns that view controller to the local
>   constant sourceViewController, and checks to see if the meal property
>   on sourceViewController is nil.

Question: Does Swift let you have multiple conditions in your if statement when separated by commas (as in this example with the comma after `MealViewController`)?

Haven't seen this in the docs.

Comment: In the case of optionnal binding yes, for the rest use the normal if syntax to mix conditions

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yes when you write

```
if let a = optA, let b = optB, let c = optC {
    
}
```

Swift does execute the body of the `IF` only if **all the optional bindings are properly completed**.

### More

Another feature of this technique: the assignments are done in **order**.

So only if a value is properly assigned to `a`, Swift tries to assign a value to `b`. And so on.

This allows you to use the previous defined variable/constant like this

```
if let a = optA, let b = a.optB {

}
```

In this case (in second assignment) we are safely using `a` because **we know** that if that code is executed, then `a` has been populated with a valid value.

Answer (score 33):

Yes. [Swift: Documentation: Language Guide: The Basics: Optional Binding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID333) says:

> You can include as many optional bindings and Boolean conditions in a single `if` statement as you need to, separated by commas. If any of the values in the optional bindings are `nil` or any Boolean condition evaluates to `false`, the whole `if` statement’s condition is considered to be `false`. The following `if` statements are equivalent:
>
> ```
> if let firstNumber = Int("4"), let secondNumber = Int("42"), firstNumber < secondNumber && secondNumber < 100 {
>     print("\(firstNumber) < \(secondNumber) < 100")
> }   
> // Prints "4 < 42 < 100"
>
> if let firstNumber = Int("4") {
>     if let secondNumber = Int("42") {
>         if firstNumber < secondNumber && secondNumber < 100 {
>             print("\(firstNumber) < \(secondNumber) < 100")
>         }   
>     }   
> }   
> // Prints "4 < 42 < 100"
> ```

Comment: I myself never knew about the `where` clause until looking it up in the docs, you learn something new every day... :)

Comment: [`where` clauses are no longer used like that in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md), just replace `where` with a comma instead.

Comment: Why would you use the comma approach versus the conditional and statement?

Comment: FYI, `where` clauses in `if` statements are no longer valid in Swift 4+. I believe it was removed in Swift 3 but I can't find a reference)

Comment: @PeejWeej Yes, with Swift 4 you can't use where, instead use a comma.

Comment: Is using the comma the same as using && i.e. and?
if let a = optA && let b = optB && let c = optC {

Comment: @mretondo, in Swift 4.1, at least, your example gives the error *Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition*, along with the suggestion to fix by replacing the `&&` with `,`. Using the comma is a way to ensure you don't have an optional, while using `&&` indicates a boolean test. To use `&&` you'd have to say this instead: `if optA != nil && optB != nil && optC != nil {`. Alternatively, if you need those unwrapped variables inside the block, you could use commas again: `if let a = optA, a>1, let b = optB, b>1, let c = optC, c>1 { return a + b + c }`

Answer (score 2):

Triggered by a code fragment that was suggested by ChatGPT I played with the comma separator (",") as an equivalent of the common AND separator ("&&"). They seem to be equivalent, although I could not find it in the Swift documentation. It is documented for the use in optional binding though (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/thebasics/#Optional-Binding)

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
let c = 3

if a == 1, c == 3 {
    print("a == 1, c == 3")
}
// prints "a == 1, c == 3"

if a == 1, b == 2, c == 3 {
    print("a == 1, b == 2, c == 3")
}
// prints "a == 1, b == 2, c == 3"

if a == 1, b == 1, c == 1 {
    print("a == 1, b == 1, c == 1")
}
else {
    print("not a == 1, b == 1, c == 1")
}
// prints "not a == 1, b == 1, c == 1"
```