# Separating multiple if conditions with commas in Swift

Tags: swift

We already know [multiple optional bindings can be used in a single if/guard statement by separating them with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434939/swift-if-statement-multiple-conditions-separated-by-commas), but not with `&&` e.g.

```
// Works as expected
if let a = someOpt, b = someOtherOpt {
}
// Crashes
if let a = someOpt && b = someOtherOpt {
}
```

Playing around with playgrounds, the comma-style format also seems to work for boolean conditions though I can't find this mentioned anywhere.  e.g.

```
if 1 == 1, 2 == 2 {
}
// Seems to be the same as
if 1 == 1 && 2 == 2 {
}
```

Is this an accepted method for evaluating multiple boolean conditions, and is the behaviour of `,` identical to that of `&&` or are they technically different?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Actually the result is not the same. Say that you have 2 statements in an if and && between them. If in the first one you create a let using optional binding, you won't be able to see it in the second statement. Instead, using a comma, you will.

Comma example:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: n, section: 0)), cell.isSelected {
    //Everything ok
}
```

&& Example:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: n, section: 0)) && cell.isSelected {
    //ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'              
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct but the answer already states the behaviour you described and the question is asking about evaluating boolean conditionals specifically.

Comment: Yes but in the other answer people is saying the results are the **same** and they're not. This is dangerous for people coming here and reading the answer, that's why I specified.

Answer (score 13):

In Swift 3, the `where` keyword in condition clauses were replaced by a comma instead.

So a statement like `if 1 == 1, 2 == 2 {}` is saying "if 1 equals 1 where 2 equals 2..."

It's probably easiest to read a conditional statement with an `&&` instead of a `,`, but the results are the same.

You can read more about the details of the change in Swift 3 in the Swift Evolution proposal: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md

Comment: So `1==1` is evaluated first?  And if `1==1` (say) was to be `false`, would `2==2` still be evaluated, or would it be skipped as `&&` does?

Comment: `2 == 2` is skipped, just like `&&` does

Comment: conditions are evaluated in direct order, even though one can think that `if 1 equals 1 where 2 equals 2...` from the answer implies that the part after `where` is evaluated first. It's not. The order is direct: `1==1`, then `2==2`.
Also, read [mrc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48523772/1364257) about `,` vs `&&` difference in the `if let` statements.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to evaluating boolean comma-separated conditions, the easies way to think of a comma is a pair or brackets. 
So, if you have

```
if true, false || true {}
```

It gets transformed into

```
if true && (false || true) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_condition-list

The Swift grammar says that the `if` statement `condition-list` can be composed by multiple `condition` separated by commas `,`

[image]

A simple condition can be a boolean `expression`, a `optional-binding-condition` or other things:

[image]

So, using the comma to separate multiple expressions is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a case where they are sufficiently different as to require the `,`.  The following code will yield

> 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

```
class User: NSObject, NSCoding {

    public var profiles: [Profile] = []    
    private var selectedProfileIndex : Int = 0

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // self.profiles initialized here

        let selectedIndex : Int = 100
        if 0 <= selectedIndex && selectedIndex < self.profiles.count {  <--- error here
            self.selectedProfileIndex = selectedIndex
        }

        super.init()
    }

...
}
```

This is due to the [definition of && on Bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922486/strange-self-captured-by-a-closure-before-all-members-were-initialized-error):

```
static func && (lhs: Bool, rhs: @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

The `selectedIndex < self.profiles.count` on the RHS is caught in a closure.

Changing the `&&` to `,` will get rid of the error.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how `,` is defined, but I thought that this was interesting.

Answer (score 2):

If you use comma, the compiler treats the whole thing like nested if's:

```
if conditionA, conditionB {
```

is treated like

```
if conditionA {
    if conditionB {
```

That's why

```
if let a = b, a > 10 {
```

works but

```
if let a = b && a > 10 {
```

does not! As the first one is in fact equivalent to

```
if b != nil {
    let a = b!
    if a > 10 {
```

yet in the second case, everything happens within the same scope and in that scope `a` was not defined, that's why [you get](https://onlinegdb.com/6Dr05yBsQ)

```
main.swift:3:17: error: cannot find 'a' in scope
```

Answer (score 0):

When pattern matching a associated value in a switch, it matters when using a `,` or `&&`. One compiles, the other won't (Swift 5.1). This compiles (`&&`):

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case integer(Int)
}

func process(someEnum: SomeEnum) {
    switch someEnum {
    // Compiles
    case .integer(let integer) where integer > 10 && integer < 10:
        print("hi")
    default:
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

This won't (`,`):

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case integer(Int)
}

func process(someEnum: SomeEnum) {
    switch someEnum {
    // Compiles
    case .integer(let integer) where integer > 10, integer < 10:
        print("hi")
    default:
        fatalError()
    }
}
```