# Swift and multiple conditions?

Tags: swift, closures

```
struct Parser<A> {
    let parse: (String) -> (A,String)?
}

func character(condition:@escaping (Character) -> Bool) -> Parser<Character> {
    return Parser(parse: {str in
        guard let char = str.first, condition(char) else {
            return nil
        }
        return (char,String(str.dropFirst()))
    })
}
```

In the code above, I have hard time figuring out what happens. More specific, what does

```
let char = str.first, condition(char)
```

do? Is this even a legal construct? The code compiles so it must be, but what is happening? `let char = str.first` is an assignment and `condition(char)` is a boolean. How can you have an assignment followed by a comma, followed by something that evaluates to a boolean.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44989227/1187415.

Comment: That explains the comma, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> More specific, what does
>
> ```
>    let char = str.first, condition(char)
> ```
>
> do?

Nothing. There is no such expression in your code.

What’s there is this:

```
guard let char = str.first, condition(char)
```

That `guard` makes all the difference. The comma joins two conditions as by nesting, so we have, in effect (since `guard` is a form of `if`):

```
if let char = str.first
```

and

```
if condition(char)
```

You understand both of those well enough, surely? If not, the only remaining thing that might be unfamiliar to you is `if let`, which is extremely fundamental to Swift and easy to learn about; it unwraps the Optional safely, avoiding the danger of crashing thru an attempt to unwrap nil.

Comment: See http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_conditional_binding for more.

Comment: Not that it really changes your answer but the OP has `guard let`, not `if let`.

Comment: @rmaddy Actually I think it's worth smoothing out that point in the answer; I've done so.