# SwiftFormat: What is the reasoning behind andOperator rule?

Tags: swift

SwiftFormat: What is the reasoning behind andOperator rule? 
https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat/blob/master/Rules.md#andOperator

Comment: I do *not* consider that a useful rule. You need the comma if you combine optional binding with other boolean tests (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/35434939/1187415), but otherwise there is no reason for it.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56568171/1187415 is an example where there is a subtle difference, but I still do not see a reason to generally replace `&&` by a comma.