# What's the difference between a comma separated conditional and one that uses a double ampersand

Tags: swift, conditional-statements

I've recently come across this type of scenario using `if/let` and understand what it does thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35434939/3046413). To my understanding, *both conditions need to be met before the proceeding block is executed*. I now have come to a point where I've seen it in a regular conditional statement:

```
if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil, replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
    return false
} else {
    return true
}
```

What's the difference between doing the above and simply using `&&` as seen below?:

```
if existingTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil {
    return false
} else {
    return true
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no practical differences. As is the case in a lot of places, there are multiple ways to do the same thing. It's possible some standard will develop on when one or the other should be used. Until then you can probably just do what you like.

Answer (score 10):

There does not appear to be a difference between using `&&` for grouping conditionals and using commas. I too have so far only seen it used with optional binding, but apparently it also works for regular conditionals, as the following snippet works fine.

```
let bool1 = true;
let bool2 = true;

if bool1 , bool2 {
    print("true");
} else {
    print("false")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The comma is used when optional binding with boolean conditions, for example `if let a = a, a.isValid()` whereas `&&` is a typical `AND` operator

Comment: Yes but in this case there's no optional binding.